# Sending complex types in Custom API requests

Tags: magento-1.7, soap-api-v2

I'm extending the SOAP API in a magento 1.7.0.2 installation. For some reason, the API is not receiving a complex data i'm sending in the request.

Is there something wrong in my definitions?

**wsdl.xml**

```
<!-- inside types tag -->
<complexType name="reviewCreateData">
    <all>
        <element name="review" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" >
        </element>
        <element name="isPositive" type="xsd:boolean" minOccurs="0" >
        </element>
        <element name="parentReviewId" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="0" >
        </element>
    </all>
</complexType>

...snip...

<message name="myCreateProductReviewRequest">
    <part name="sessionId" type="xsd:string"> </part>
    <part name="dato" type="typens:reviewCreateData"></part>
</message>

...snip...
```

**Api.php**

```
public function createProductReview($dato){
    Mage::log(__METHOD__);

    Mage::log("dato");
    if(isset($dato)){
        Mage::log('dato received');
        Mage::log($dato['review']);
    }
    else{
        Mage::log('dato not received');
    }

    // $reviewId = $this->_createReview($productId, $customerId, $review, $isPositive, $parentReviewId);
    $reviewId = 9999;

    $result = [];
    $result['success'] = true;
    $result['message'] = "created review $reviewId";
    return $result;
}
```

After every request, i'm getting the "dato not received" message.